Referencing another databucket in mockoon
I am mocking a real estate app api in mockoon. which has a crud path of api/properties. I also have two data buckets, agents and properties. In the properties data bucket, I want the agent_id to reference one random id field in the agents data bucket
Here is how my data buckets looks like:
agents
[
  {{#repeat 100}}
    {
      "id":"{{faker 'string.uuid'}}",
      "name":"{{faker 'person.fullName'}}",
      "email":"{{faker 'internet.email'}}",
    }
  {{/repeat}}
]

properties
[
  {{#repeat 100}}
    {
      "property_id": "{{faker 'string.uuid'}}",
      "agent_id": "{{oneOf (data 'agents' 'id')}}",
      "title": "{{faker 'commerce.productName'}}",
      "description": "{{faker 'lorem.paragraph'}}",
      "price": "{{faker 'commerce.price'}}",
      "location": "{{faker 'address.city'}}",
      "latitude": "{{faker 'address.latitude'}}",
      "longitude": "{{faker 'address.longitude'}}",
      "property_type": "{{oneOf (array 'apartment' 'house' 'condo' 'townhouse')}}",
      "status": "{{oneOf (array 'for sale' 'sold' 'pending')}}",
      "created_at": "{{faker 'date.past'}}",
      "updated_at": "{{faker 'date.recent'}}",
      "image_url": "{{oneOf (array 'house1.jpg' 'house2.jpg' 'house3.jpg' 'house4.jpg' 'house5.jpeg' 'house6.jpeg' 'house7.jpeg' 'house8.jpeg' 'house9.jpeg' 'house10.jpeg' 'house11.jpeg')}}",
      "featured": {{boolean}}
    }
  {{/repeat}}
]

But when I start the server i get an empty field for the agent_id. Here is a sample response:
[
    {
        "property_id": "34a31030-dbe4-45b5-ae15-a4995afe50b5",
        "agent_id": "",
        "title": "Incredible Granite Towels",
        "description": "Abutor ustilo cernuus alter. Hic suffoco bibo argentum asper vergo aranea. Solium anser tenus vulnero bellicus commemoro arma.",
        "price": "51.00",
        "location": "Rock Hill",
        "latitude": "2.935",
        "longitude": "127.208",
        "property_type": "house",
        "status": "for sale",
        "created_at": "Tue Aug 13 2024 23:07:17 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)",
        "updated_at": "Sun Sep 01 2024 08:41:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)",
        "image_url": "house7.jpeg",
        "featured": true
    },
    {
        "property_id": "d4e92c48-eca7-43a4-9f46-3e425dc2ab58",
        "agent_id": "",
        "title": "Fantastic Steel Sausages",
        "description": "Timidus appello sponte condico considero cohaero desipio temperantia. Ab ambitus volup ullam uxor hic ager. Viduo dedecor aperiam.",
        "price": "473.00",
        "location": "North Lonnie",
        "latitude": "5.9764",
        "longitude": "-116.9723",
        "property_type": "condo",
        "status": "pending",
        "created_at": "Mon Feb 19 2024 09:37:47 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)",
        "updated_at": "Sun Sep 01 2024 17:06:16 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)",
        "image_url": "house5.jpeg",
        "featured": true
    },
    ...
]

I read other answers to a similar question which recommended something like this:
"agent_id": "{{{stringify (oneOf (dataRaw 'agents' 'id'))}}}",
But it still returned an empty field
